# Is it possible to power down the GPU completely under software control

Tags: gpu, power-management

I have been thinking about a new PC build recently which would, mostly, not need a GPU to be active but which, ideally, would have access to one when it needs it.

As power consumption is an issue, but space is not, I would ideally like to be able to power down the GPU completely under software control. I could then use e.g. a keyboard action to trigger the turning on. Is this possible?

Note that while GPUs do go into lower power states when not doing heavy workloads, this is — for my purposes — still too high. When required I would need a powerful GPU and it will need to provide graphics output as a display device as well.

The OS can be either Linux or Windows 10, but ideally Linux. It's going to be a fresh OS install but the application it must run is on either of those platforms.

Can one power down a specific PCI-e card from software and then restart it all later? I suspect not with current mainstream OSes.

Looking to do this on Linux or Windows 10, but ideally Linux. It's going to be a fresh OS install but the application it **must** run is on either of those platforms.